# Full trusted SSL on localhsot

Tags: iis, ssl

I'm writing a webservice that is to be consumed by a third party tool. The tool only accepts the service to on full trusted SSL. I tried to create https://localhost using [Makecert.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but the problem is that ssl created with this are not fully trusted so the thrid party tool does not accept it. Is there any way I can create a fully trusted SSL website on my dev environment for testing.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pre-trusted CA will issue a certificate to `localhost`, since it's the local host name for everyone.

You would need to import that certificate explicitly into your client tool. How this is done will depend on what this client tool is using. You could start by importing the certificate (not the private key) in your list of trusted root authorities in Windows.